# Run a Virtual Machine faster than real-time

Tags: virtual-machine, virtualbox, system-clock

I'm trying to run a binary faster its' real-time execution, and assumed Virtual Box may have a way in doing so, based off of [this 10-year old post](https://www.virtualbox.org/ticket/5768).

I need to emulate Windows 10. Is this possible, on any VM out there?

Comment: Is this question about programming?

Comment: Please note that the article talks about clock speed (i.e. time flows faster or slower), not CPU speed. If this is really what you want, the last comment on the linked issue should point you in the right direction.

Comment: Possibly. Whether it be a setting in a VM somewhere, or required changes to an open source VM, both are viable options. You reckon I post this somewhere else?

Comment: @Eric - This is a site purely dedicated to programming questions. Your question should be directly about programming.

Answer (score 3):

Great documentation on the docs here, 2.13.2

https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E97728_01/F12469/html/fine-tune-timers.html

As explained above, using the command

`VBoxManage setextradata "VM name" "VBoxInternal/TM/WarpDrivePercentage" 200`

manages to set the clock to update 200% faster.

Comment: Link-only answers are frowned upon. Links should only be used to support content you have already put in your answer.

Comment: does not work beyond VirtualBox 4.2 as it seems